# How to set a maximum amount of clicks on an order button for each item specifically? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to implement a functionality where the user can only order a set amount of times (let's take 5 times for example) before an alert shows up saying that the product he is trying to order has *ran out of stock*.

He can still of course, order other product that haven't been clicked on 5 times.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to keep count of each order button (an anchor acting as a button) specifically.

I tried implementing that functionality and it does show an alert, but it takes count of all order buttons clicked.

This is how my functions looks:

```
let counter = 0; //global variable
function order_func() {
    let every_product= document.querySelectorAll(".all_prods");
    for (let each_prod = 0; each_prod < every_product.length; each_prod++) {
        every_product[each_prod].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if(count_stuff < 10){
                add_it(e, each_prod); //e to preventDefault() and console.log "each_prod"
            count_stuff++;
        }else{
            out_of_stock(e); //shows the alert it takes the event as argument to prevent default behavior.
        }

        });
    }

}
```

`add_it()` is just a function that `console.log()`'s the product.

I'm only using vanilla JS, I don't want to use any other libraries for this :)

Comment: Create a counter for each button in your loop ... `counters[each_prod] = 0`,

Comment: @chipit24 It says that I can't create a counter that way `let counters[each_prod] = 0;`. It's expecting a `newline or semicolon` inside the `[]`

Comment: Use the target of the event (e.target == the anchor) then use an identifying property of that anchor and a sibling/parent element etc. and count based upon that identifying property.

Answer (score 0):

you can use data attribute to store temp values in page. take a look on this example using JQuery.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<a href="" id="order-btn" data-count="0" data-max-counts="5">Order</a>

<script>
$('#order-btn').click(function() {
    var maxCounts = this.data('maxCounts');
    var count = this.data('count');
    if (count >= maxCount) {
       alert('you cant order any more');
       return;
    }
    this.data('count',count++);

   // other logic .e.g Ajax call

})
</script>
```

you can do it using vanilla JS also:

```
<script>
    let counter = 0; //global variable
        function order_func() {
           let every_product= document.querySelectorAll(".all_prods");
           for (let each_prod = 0; each_prod < every_product.length; each_prod++) {
             every_product[each_prod].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
               var count_stuff = e.target.dataset.count; // or this.dataset.count
               var max_count = e.target.dataset.maxCounts; // or this.dataset.maxCounts
               if(count_stuff < max_count){
                  add_it(e, each_prod); 
                  e.target.dataset.count = count_stuff++;
               }else{
                 out_of_stock(e); 
               }

        });
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use any libraries, only vanilla JS. I apologize for not elaborating!

Comment: @RandyCasburn using jquery to show an example of storing data in element , which all question about.

Comment: @HassanJuniedi - The OP (KoyaCho) in the previous comment to yours said "**I'm not trying to use any libraries, only vanilla JS.**" You should change your answer to use "_only vanilla JS_".